# jQuery Click a button using jQuery and append data to response after ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have two buttons and one of them is already bound with an ajax call from a different site. I need to call the ajax using the first button and also I need to append some data to the result after ajax completion.

> I have no access to edit the ajax function or existing jQuery. All I can do is that create a new function. So please don't ask me to edit ajax jQuery or function.

Simply I need to call this from the console. Is there any jQuery function to know whether an ajax is called and that one has a success response.

I tried to use [ajaxStart()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [ajaxStop()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/). But not working.

This what I tried.

```js
jQuery('.a').click(function(){
  var valuetopass;
  //Copy Value from input of A
  jQuery(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    console.log('Click Ajax Button');
    valuetopass = jQuery('.a_value').val();
  });

  //Call Ajax
  jQuery('.b').click();

  //Paste Value to the result appended
  jQuery(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    console.log('Appended the result input field(b_value) to the html.');
    
    //Paste the value in new field from ajax.
    jQuery('.b_value').val(valuetopass);
  });
});
```

```html
<input class="a_value" value="ABC"/>
<button class="a">Button to initiate ajax</button>
<button class="b">Button having Ajax</button>
```

Here when we click on button `A` it will initiate a click on button `B` and ajax will call.
After that, the result will append an input field in HTML like `<input class="b_value"/>` . I need to add value to this field using an external jQuery function.

I have also tried

```
setTimeout(function(){
  jQuery('.b_value').val(valuetopass)
},500);
```

But we can't say 500 ms will be the exact time taken. Is there any possibility to find the ajax called and finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use .ajaxComplete(), use it like this

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
  console.log(xhr.responseText);
});
```

Here xhr.responseText will be having the response of every ajax call made by jQuery ajax method.
So your response `<input class="b_value"/>` can be processed inside this callback

Comment: Appreciate it. I can use this in a different way to achieve. Thanks

Comment: Actually, I need to do this only when I click the `.a` button. So we need to unbind the ajaxComplete after it called.

`$('body').ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, options) {
      if (options.url == '/expected/url.html') { // Or whatever test you may need
            doStuff();
            $(e.currentTarget).unbind('ajaxComplete');
      }
});
`